# Delete rows with no entries in matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have imported data. {{...},{...},{...},...{...}}

Here a screenshot:
[image]

As you can see there are empty entires {,,,,,,}

**How can I delete those entries ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete rows that only consist of empty strings:

```
DeleteCases[data, {"" ..}]
```

`"" ..` is a pattern for "1 or more empty strings in a row". `..` is shorthand for [Repeated](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html).

Comment: Very elegant ! Good explenation! Thank you.

Comment: `DeleteCases[{{1,""}, {2,""}, {}}, {"" ..}]` doesn't give me the same result as I have in my answer.  Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @Gerli: If I want to delete rows with `Complex Number`, then how do you revise your code above?

Comment: @TugrulTemel if you want to delete rows that only have complex numbers then instead of `""` use `_Complex` as the pattern for the element to delete (ending up with `{_Complex ..}` -- or you can use  `{__Complex}` which is equivalent in this case). From the wording of your question it seems like you might want to delete rows that contain a complex number, in which case the pattern you want could be `{___, _Complex, ___}` (0 or more elements, then a complex number, then 0 or more elements in the list)

Comment: @Gerli:  I wanted to delete the rows with complex numbers, and your suggestion works fine. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Those are probably empty strings, so:

```
DeleteCases[{1,"",""}, ""]
```

will probably work for a single list. For lists of lists, you can use `Map`:

```
Map[ DeleteCases[#, ""] &, listOfLists]
```

If you would like to delete remaining empty rows, you can augment this with another `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[
  Map[ DeleteCases[#, ""] &, listOfLists]
, {}]
```

Comment: Hmm ... it is not working. It is working for your problem, but in my case I have rows witch are only empty strings.

Comment: Please try my edited response.

Comment: Very close... it delets all the empty entries but leaves the brakets {}. I have found a way to get rid of them. DeleteCases[Map[DeleteCases[#, ""] &, resMat], {}]

Comment: please add my solution to your response, so that I can validate your answer. :)

Comment: I made the edit.

Comment: `DeleteCases[listOfLists, "", {2}]` is a cleaner way of deleting items from a nested list.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 4, 9}, {"", "", ""}, {3, 4, 1}, {"", "", ""}};

list //. "" | {} :> Nothing
```

{{2, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 1}}

```
Delete[Position[list, {"" ..}]] @ list
```

{{2, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `Pick` and `NumberQ`:

```
list = {{2, 4, 9}, {"", "", ""}, {3, 4, 1}, {"", "", ""}};

Pick[#, AllTrue[#, NumberQ] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{2, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 1}}*)
```